# writing a pass test in javascript need a review for my code

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd

I am learning and practicing to write a test:

Here is the test case `add-numbers.test.js`:

```
var addAllnumbers = require("./add-numbers");
test("Add all numbers", function () {
  var numbers = [9, 23, 10, 3, 8];
  var expected = 53;

  var output = addAllnumbers(numbers);

  expect(output).toEqual(expected);
});
```

here is `add-numbers.js`:

```
function addNumbers(numbers) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    sum += numbers[i];
  }

  return sum;
}
module.exports = addNumbers;
```

Did I do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that looks right!  Can I ask why you are using the `.required()` instead of having that function in the same file?  Either works, just curious.

Also, you should try to incorporate modern syntax whenever possible (that is if you can understand exactly what is happening).

But the following method does the same as yours but doesn't require another method:

```
let numbers = [9, 23, 10, 3, 8];
let expected = 53;
    
var sum = array.reduce((a, b) => {
              return a + b;
          }, 0);

expect(sum).toEqual(expected);
```

Comment: Oh I have no idea clone a github repo for these practice assigments https://github.com/nathannewyen/js-exercises-tdd